# Detect Nearby Users and Notify with Push Notification iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I'm looking to incorporate a feature within my mobile app where I am alerted via `push notification` of nearby users who also have the mobile app and is identified as my "friend" - even when the app is in the background.

Example: User A and User B are friends within the app, User A is within proximity of User B. Both are alerted of each other's presence.

Is there any recommended solution I should look into to fulfill this use case? I am aware of `iBeacons`, `BLE` and `Multipeer Network Connectivity`, but admittedly don't fully grasp them conceptually and what is possible. Also, any available tutorial for a beginner? I have tried scouring the web and could not find any.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: you can check user location in background and calculate distance between users on server side and sent notifications if needed

Comment: "you can check user location in background..." No, you can't. Only turn-by-turn GPS apps are allowed to constantly read from the GPS from the background. Other apps only get a few minutes of background time before they are suspended and stop getting background time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a solution that will let you do this when the device is locked. You can monitor for iBeacon signals from the background, and your app will even get launched when it detects a beacon. However, all the copies of your app would need to broadcast beacon signals, and you can't do that while the device is locked, or for more than a couple of minutes while your app is in the background.

The same is true for monitoring your GPS location and broadcasting it to a network. You might be able to use the "significant location change" notification to detect when the user moves a substantial distance, but that might not give you the resolution you need.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Would the following potentially work? Allow location background updates and monitor significant location changes with a location manager, and on `didUpdateLocations` delegate method, fire a function that triggers the backend to logic whether other users are nearby based on coordinates that are saved when other users have their own `didUpdateLocations` fire? And send push notifications thereafter?

Comment: Yes, that should work, but you might not get the resolution or speedy updates you need. I suggest setting up a test app with significant location change notifications set up, and make it beep each time your app gets an update, and show the location update as a pin on a map Then walk around and gauge if it's frequent and/or accurate enough for your needs.